# $scope.watch being called too many times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-controller

I thought I had this problem solved but it turns out I didn't so any offers of help would be much appreciated.

Basically, I'm having trouble with my controllers and scopes which is causing my $scope.$watch() to be called when I don't want it to.

I have an Angular view (html) with a dropdown and pagination tag using different controllers and views.

First, I have this: (where form_item_Division.html is simply a dropdown of Divisions)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary panel-shad-1" ng-controller="DashboardIEPItemDraftCtrl">
        <div ng-include="'views/partials/form_item_Division.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'app/dashboard/iep.html'" ng-controller="DashboardIEPItemDraftCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

My iep.html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardIEPItemDraftCtrl">
<div ng-include="'app/dashboard/iepitem_table1.html'" ng-if="numberOfItemsByUserDivision > 0"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" ng-show="totalNumberPages > 1">
            <pagination items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
                    total-items="numberOfItemsByUserDivision"
                    ng-model="currentPage"
                    max-size="3"
                    boundary-links="true"
                    rotate="false"
                    class="pagination-sm panel-shad-1"
                    num-pages="totalNumberPages"
                    previous-text="&lsaquo;"
                    next-text="&rsaquo;"
                    first-text="&laquo;"
                    last-text="&raquo;">
            </pagination>
        </div>
</div>
```

My iepitem_table1.html defines the table layout and is under a different controller.  It looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" ng-controller="IEPItemTableCtrl">

   (table layout defined here)

</table>
```

The relevant part of my script is shown below:

```
$scope.getItemsBySelectedDivision = function (selectedDivisionId) {
   blah.get({ count: true, filter: 'DivisionPerformingId eq ' +   
   selectedDivisionId }).$promise.then(
      function (response) {
         $scope.itemsByUserDivision.length = 0;
         $scope.itemsByUserDivision = response.value;
         $scope.numberOfItemsByUserDivision = response.value.length;
         $scope.totalNumberPages = Math.ceil(response.value.length /    
         $scope.itemsPerPage);
         var pagedData = $scope.itemsByUserDivision.slice(0, 
         $scope.itemsPerPage);
         $scope.itemsByUserDivision = pagedData;
      },
      function (error) {
          // Do something when it errors
      });
        };

$scope.$watch("currentPage", function () {
   if ($scope.itemsByUserDivision != null) {
     $scope.itemsByUserDivision = originalItems;
     var pagedData = $scope.itemsByUserDivision.slice(($scope.currentPage -  
     1) * $scope.itemsPerPage, $scope.currentPage * $scope.itemsPerPage);
     $scope.itemsByUserDivision = pagedData;
 }
 });
```

When I select a Division from the dropdown and scroll through the pages with the pagination tag everything is fine.  However, when I scroll through the pages of a division that has more than one page and then go back and select another Division the results shown are not correct.  I think this is because my $scope.$watch() is being called when I don't want it to.  I think I don't have my controllers arranged properly for this scenario.  At any rate, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can compare for change in variable you are watching,

```
    $scope.$watch("currentPage", function (oldVal,newVal) {
        if(newVal!==oldVal){
               if ($scope.itemsByUserDivision != null) {
               $scope.itemsByUserDivision = originalItems;
               var pagedData =$scope.itemsByUserDivision.slice(($scope.currentPage -  
         1) * $scope.itemsPerPage, $scope.currentPage *  $scope.itemsPerPage);
         $scope.itemsByUserDivision = pagedData;
     }
   }  
     });
```

Comment: Hi Ved, I did try to do this but wasn't able to.  Can you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: Are you still facing problem?